# How can I send data to other component in Angular?

Tags: angular

As I understand, the parent component can send data to child component by using @Input(). In this case, child will be able to use data at .html page. However, I want to use the data in .ts file.

For instance, I send the google.maps.Map type data to child component and then I want to use the data at my child component's .ts page.
Is it possible to use?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes you can access the value

Comment: How can I access the data? Could you give me a keyword for googling?

Comment: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/custom-directives/inputs-and-configuration/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<child-component [inputParam]="map"></child-component>
```

in your .ts:

```
@Input() inputParam;

ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.inputParam)
}
```